# Graphql Java upload scalar maximum size

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I will like to limit the maximum size of the Upload scalar parameter by using schema directives but it does not work. See my code below:

```
directive @Size(min : Int = 0, max : Int = 1, message : String = "graphql.validation.Size.message") on ARGUMENT_DEFINITION | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

directive @Max(value : Int = 1048576, message : String = "graphql.validation.Max.message") on SCALAR

scalar Upload @Max

type Mutation {
    uploadFile(files: [Upload!] @Size(max : 1)): boolean
}
```

Looking forward to receiving help from everyone.